# R Count Values of every Column in Dataframe

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I can do it using group by with only one Column but I want the Count for every Column in the Dataframe. See example:

Dataframe with similar values in each Column:
df =

```
      C1       C2       C3
 
1   Positiv  Negativ  Neutral
2   NA       Neutral  Positiv
3   Positiv  NA       Negativ
4   Negativ  Positiv  NA
```

I thought about something like this:

`df %>% group_by(names(df))  %>% count()`

desired Output: Count Values in each Column

```
                C1   C2  C3
 
1 Positive      2     1   1
2 Negative      1     1   1
3 Neutral       0     1   1
4 NA            1     1   1
```

Comment: `sapply(df, table)`

Comment: `table(stack(df), useNA = "ifany")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this with some `tidyverse` functions and reshaping your data to long and wide:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=N,values_fill=0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  value      C1    C2    C3
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 Negativ     1     1     1
2 Positiv     2     1     1
3 NA          1     1     1
4 Neutral     0     1     1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(C1 = c("Positiv", NA, "Positiv", "Negativ"), C2 = c("Negativ", 
"Neutral", NA, "Positiv"), C3 = c("Neutral", "Positiv", "Negativ", 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: ha ha @Duck, yet again beat me to it. Deleting mine.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` with `table`

```
sapply(df,  function(x) table(factor(x,
      levels = c('Negativ', 'Positiv', 'Neutral')), useNA = "always"))
#        C1 C2 C3
#Negativ  1  1  1
#Positiv  2  1  1
#Neutral  0  1  1
#<NA>     1  1  1
```

---

Or using a vectorized approach

```
table(unlist(df), c(col(df)), useNA = 'always')[, -4]
         
#          1 2 3
#  Negativ 1 1 1
#  Neutral 0 1 1
#  Positiv 2 1 1
#  <NA>    1 1 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c("Positiv", NA, "Positiv", "Negativ"), C2 = c("Negativ", 
"Neutral", NA, "Positiv"), C3 = c("Neutral", "Positiv", "Negativ", 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: `useNA = "ifany"` is probably more appropriate in your second approach.